# duplicate key value violates unique constraint "auth_user_username_key"DETAIL: Key (username)=(None) already exists

Tags: python, django

I want to register a user using a custom register model but I keep getting the following error :

> duplicate key value violates unique constraint "auth_user_username_key" DETAIL:  Key (username)=(None) already exists

How do I fix this error.

This is the code I have created thus far:

In **urls.py** I create url configurations for the various pages.

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth.views import login


from . import views

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$', views.nest, name = 'nest'),

    url(r'^login/$', login, {'template_name' : 'Identities/login.html'}, name = 'login'),

    url(r'^register/$', views.register, name = 'register'),
]
```

In **forms.py** I create the custom registration form.

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

# Create custom user registration


class CreateAccountForm(UserCreationForm):

    email = forms.EmailField(required = True)


    class Meta:

        model = User

        fields = (

            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'password1',
            'password2'
        )

        def save(self, commit = True):
            user = super(CreateAccountForm, self).save(commit = False)
            user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
            user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
            user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']

            if commit:

                user.save()

            return user
```

In **views.py** I created the register view function.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from Identities.forms import CreateAccountForm

# Create your views here.

def nest(request):
    return render(request, 'Identities/nest.html')


def register(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = CreateAccountForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

        else:
            return redirect(reverse('Identities:logout'))

    else:

        form = CreateAccountForm()
        var = {'form' : form}
        return render(request, 'Identities/create_account.html', var)
```

Comment: You are trying to use Django default User model, and in the form you have excluded the `username` field (why?). `username` is unique, hence you have already stored one user without username, you won't be able to do that again coz `None` already stored once, hence the error.

Answer (score 4):

You need to include `username` in your form. Coz **username** being a unique field can't be excluded in form. And if you are excluding it in form then, you need to **handle it by generating the unique username** for every user which is bit tedious.

```
class CreateAccountForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required = True)

    class Meta:
        model = User

        fields = (
             'username'
             'first_name',
             'last_name',
             'email',
             'password1',
             'password2'
        )
   . . . . . .
   . . . . . .
```

Answer (score 1):

You should really try something like below. Here, I have included username to your form fields. Since username is unique, it should be included in form fields. In the save method, `self.cleaned_data.get("username", None)` takes None to username field if nothing posted in the request. Your **db** expects **None** if no value given, but if you don't specify it in the save method, it receives empty strings, which causes duplicate key error. **Note** that Django does not store empty values as **None**, but uses empty string instead.

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

# Create custom user registration


class CreateAccountForm(UserCreationForm):

    email = forms.EmailField(required = True)


    class Meta:

        model = User

        fields = (
            'username',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'password1',
            'password2'
        )

        def save(self, commit = True):
            user = super(CreateAccountForm, self).save(commit = False)
            user.username = self.cleaned_data.get("username", None)
            user.first_name = self.cleaned_data.get("first_name", None)
            user.last_name = self.cleaned_data.get("last_name", None)
            user.email = self.cleaned_data.get("email", None)

            if commit:

                user.save()

            return user
```